# Error en intento android

Tags: android, android-intent

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]He creado un intento muy sencillo que al clickar en un botón con el `onClick()` lleve a otra `Activity`:

```
public void ejecutarInfo(View view){
        Intent intento = new Intent(this, InfoClass.class);

        startActivity(intento);
}
```

Error que sale:

```
the onclick atribute value should be the name of a method in this
views context to invoke the  view when is clicked
```

y me dice que el metodo debe tener de parametro una vista la cual tiene.

Gracias. =)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor podrías agregar el código donde el onClick()

Comment: ¿En el XML de tu botón tienes definido el método `ejecutarInfo` como `onClick`?

Comment: El método no se encuentra en la misma Activity que da click el botón!

Comment: he añadido las fotos de la declaracion del metodo y el error. Muchas gracias por su tiempo

Comment: El problema está en que estás cargando el info.xml y no el main.xml, que es donde se encuentra tu botón con tu metodo.

Comment: El problema habia sido que no habia instanciado en AndoridManifest la nueva Activity. Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error esta en que estas inflando la vista de info.xml, deberias de inflar activy_main.xml.

En tu MainActivity.java deberia de quedar mas o menos asi:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**De acuerdo al mensaje, el método no se encuentra en la misma clase `Activity` que da clic el botón!**

La clase `Activity` debe contener el método que debe ser llamado desde el botón que carga el layout, el botón llama el método desde el atributo `android:onClick`:

```
android:OnClick="ejecutarInfo"
```

---

Asegura que la `Activity` que carga el layout que contiene el botón, tenga el método `ejecutarInfo()`.